# Is it possible to define a parameter of a type that can not be imported but exists in another importable type?

Tags: typescript

When importing the following sample type from an external package

```
interface Config {
  aField: AField;
}

interface AField {
  subField: SubField;
}

interface SubField {}

export { Config };
```

I can expect a parameter of type `Config` like so

```
import { Config } from "external-package";

function myFn(config: Config) {}
```

but what if this function only needs the variable `subField`? It's not possible to import this type but is there a way to change the function to something like

```
import { Config } from "external-package";

function myFn(subField: Config.AField.SubField) {}
```

As a sidenote: I don't want to import that type from the node_modules directly. If that's the only way I would stick to the first approach...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```js
function myFn(subField: Config['aField']['subField']) {}
```